# How can I ensure not to creat a duplicate relationship when creating one between existing nodes?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've used the following code to create relationship between two nodes:

```
MATCH (c1), (c2)
WHERE c1.name = "UK" AND c2.name = "London"
CREATE (c2)-[:IN]->(c1);
```

If I run it few times it will duplicate the relationship. I want to avoid possible duplication. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid duplication of relationship can use the `MERGE` clause instead `CREATE`:

```
MATCH (c1), (c2)
WHERE c1.name = "UK" AND c2.name = "London"
MERGE (c2)-[:IN]->(c1);
```